# different values for one variable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i want to put the function part of the code alone, then call it back but give it a different value for the variable each time... or at least that's the idea.
i tried to do something like this to my code but it started giving me different values for one variable when i use **!test**

```
  global embed_on_raw_reaction_add, already_have_role
  already_have_role = '''old value'''  # this always get sent in the embed
  embed_on_raw_reaction_add = discord.Embed()
  embed_on_raw_reaction_add.add_field(name='@{}'.format(already_have_role), value='filler', inline=False)



@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  global already_have_role
  if message.author == bot.user:
    return
  msg = message.content.lower().replace(' ', '')


  if msg.startswith('!changeValue'):
    already_have_role = '''new value'''


  if msg.startswith('!test'): #if we do *!changeValue* before this then this happens
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed_on_raw_reaction_add) # prints the old value
    await message.channel.send(already_have_role) # prints new value
```

so the value is changing, but i don't understand why when i want to use the variable in the embed it uses the old/original value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're getting 2 separate values for `already_have_role` because Python is pass-by-reference rather than pass-by-value. What that means is when you call a variable, it just "points" to the value of the variable, rather than just the value itself.

You're seeing it here because when you call
`await message.channel.send(embed=embed_on_raw_reaction_add)`

`embed_on_raw_reaction_add` references `already_have_role` where it was instantiated (created). In this case, that's

```py
embed_on_raw_reaction_add.add_field(name='@{}'.format(already_have_role), value='filler', inline=False)
```

This line.
Since when `embed_on_raw_reaction` was instantiated, `already_have_role` was the "old" value before it was changed with `!changevalue`.

If you want them to be the same, you'll need to instantiate the embed again in `async def on_message(self)`